# How to hide the scrollbar in Layout<View>

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created the class which inherits Layout and used that in xaml view,but i need to to hide the scrollbar in that view where i used this class,

```
public class WrapView : Layout<View>
{

}
```

How to hide scrollbar in those views.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this code inside your override method

```
Xamarin.Forms.ListView.VerticalScrollbarEnabled = false;
```

Basically it just hide the vertical scroll bar in your list view